# dbvisualizer: number of rows limited by maxrows

Tags: oracle

I'm running a simple query on an Oracle database table like

```
select * from tableA
```

and DBVisualizer cuts the query short at 1000 rows.  How do I remove this limit?
Message is "number of rows limited by maxrows".

Answer (score 2):

Max rows is specified just above the SQL Commander tab in the second field from the right.   On the Object View tab it is at the bottom left of the results window.  For a single table query I generally use the Object View window.  It is easy to setup filters in the Data sub-tab.

Setting this value too high will result in a crash when you run out of memory.

Is there a reason you want more than 1000 records returned?  That's a lot of data to scroll through.